# ASM RMAN BACKUP FAILED

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I'm trying to migrate a filesystem to ASM but when I start with RMAN backup, I face the following error, which is weird because I haven't performed any backups before on the same database.

```
RMAN> BACKUP AS COPY DATABASE FORMAT 'DATA';

Starting backup at 28-JUL-15
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=24 device type=DISK
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile copy
input datafile file number=00001 name=C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ECC\SYSTEM01.DBF
output file name=C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DATA tag=TAG20150728T143422 RECID=2 STAMP=886257290
channel ORA_DISK_1: datafile copy complete, elapsed time: 00:00:35
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile copy
input datafile file number=00002 name=C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ECC\SYSAUX01.DBF
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 07/28/2015 14:34:59
ORA-19504: failed to create file "C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DATA"
ORA-27038: created file already exists
OSD-04010: <create> option specified, file already exists
```

Please advise

Comment: Does the file already exist though? Does your path include your DB name? If it doesn't might there not be something there from a previous DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If diskgroup DATA already exists in you ASM instance, the correct syntax is:
BACKUP AS COPY DATABASE FORMAT '+DATA';

regards
Giova